# Create small single page Web API without MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I have a limitation to one `.aspx` file and corresponding script file in C#.

I don't know how to use these `WebMethods` to achieve something like this:

```
Request Header: "http://localhost:8888/singlepage.aspx/file/8/items",
Type: "POST",
Data: {Description,Price}
```

Is it even possible without MVC?

Comment: Consider a client side framework (Ember, Angular, etc...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods to create page-hosted web service methods, like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SaveDescriptionAndPrice(string description, decimal price)
{
    // Do something here to save values
}
```

Now in your `.aspx` page, you can invoke the ASP.NET AJAX Page Method by using the jQuery `.ajax()` function, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "singlepage.aspx/SaveDescriptionAndPrice",
        data: "{'description':'This is a fake description.', 'price':12.99}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            // Do something interesting here.
        }
    });
});
```

Note: I hard-coded the values for the data, but you can create a JavaScript object to hold the values and `stringify()` them or use jQuery to select the values from DOM elements.

Comment: This looks like the only way to go, using `json` to pass any extra parameters.

Comment: Any tutorial how to start from scratch and have it hosted on IIS so outside people can access the API go get data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the routing engine outside of MVC - so you can use routing in webforms.

There are many walkthroughs on this subject, but this one is from MS...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.ASPX

this is what i searched for... web forms routing asp.net

Comment: +0: while valid suggestion it looks like it is not available to OP: "I have a limitation to one .aspx file and corresponding script file in C#"